# PostgreSQL: set cluster Slony I Path

Tags: postgresql, slony, enterprisedb

I have installed PostgreSQL enterprise which is have installed slony, I  try to set path in the Options Slony-I ... because when I try to make new cluster I see message:

> slony-i creation scripts not available only joining possible

I set path `C:\PostgresPlus\9.3AS\share , C:\PostgresPlus\9.3AS\lib , C:\PostgresPlus\9.3AS`, but no changes, I see again the new message and could not create cluster.
Can anyone help me? what is the right path?

Thanks

Comment: "PostgreSQL enterprise". Do you mean EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus / Advanced Server? Or do you mean the EnterpriseDB packaging of regular community PostgreSQL, their "one click" installer? Version?

Comment: Given the path ("C:\PostgresPlus\9.3AS\") most probably it's EnterpriseDB's Postgres Plus Advanced Server.

Comment: Yes Postgres Plus Advanced , also I have PG Admin III, but I do not know what is slony path? I installed slony also manually, but no result, I cant make cluster

Answer (score 1):

1)You can do the following

1. open pgadmin.
2. Go to File/options/binary paths
3. The path is **/usr/share/slony1**

Answer (score 1):

For windows users. Do the following:

**I am not responsible for data lost on step 5.**

1. Open that pgadmin3 tool.
2. Go to File/options/binary paths.

Now on Slony path:

3. The path is similar to C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.2\share (ie the share directory on posgress root).
4. Save, restart the tool, or simply reload the database tree.
5. Now that your done access and delete all your important data on cloud or external backup, Then re-install windows formatting your hard-drive.